# Where would noop be used in Ceylon

Tags: ceylon

I am playing around with this beautiful language and saw a function called `noop`.

As the documentation says it's a void function that does nothing!!

So why would I use a function that does nothing? Is it for adding "Nop" in assembly (for pipeline etc) but then this would be too low-level wouldn't it?

Comment: hmmmm why downvote, the documentation doesn't tell any usecases does it ?

Comment: yeah, totally unfair downvote. But you should correct the title and comment to be `noop`, not `noob`.

Comment: thanks @JohnVasileff , fixed my typo :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`noop()` can take the place of *any* void (or `Anything` returning) function. So it's useful to use as a value if you are calling a function or creating an object that requires you to pass in an event handler or callback function, but you aren't interested in responding to the event.

Answer (score 7):

`noop()` is also useful as the default value of an an optional parameter of a function, for example:

```
void foo(void bar(Integer i) => noop(i)) {}
```

Or:

```
void foo(Anything(Integer) bar = noop) {}
```